# How to count object from json_decode PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have returned data from json_decode

```
$xml = json_decode($res);
$data=$xml->Item;
```

And when dump `$data`in my code

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => {#500 ▼
    +"productCode": "ddddddddddddd"
    +"productNameEN": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    +"show_in_web": "aaaaaaaaaaa"
    +"visible": "N"
  }
]
```

I need to count object in each array.

```
foreach( $data as $itm ){
   dump(count($itm));die();
}
```

I used count() in foreach loop result return 1. Please help me.

Comment: `$itm` is an object, not an array.

Comment: Why do you have `die()` in the loop? It will stop after printing the first element.

Comment: What is `dump()`? Shouldn't that be `var_dump()` or `print_r()`? And why would you use that with `count($itm)`, which just returns a number? Just use `echo count($itm);`

Comment: If you want to count the number of objects, use `count($data)`.

Comment: @Barmar when i use `echo count($data)` and `echo count($itm);` it' return 1.

Comment: What's wrong with that? The dump shows that there's just one element in the array. What are you expecting?

Comment: I need to count number of object in each array. In this array 0 have **4** object.That was i need

Comment: The array has one object. That object has 4 properties. Are you trying to count the number of properties in the object?

Comment: That worked Thanks